# Constraint layout include issue

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm setting up some nested constraint layout using include, similar with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56314530/nested-include-constraint-layout) but doesn't get the answer yet.

The constraint doesn't work as it supposed to.

I have tried to change the layout in include xml to `LinearLayout`, but it still doesn't work. I've tried to add `_bias` but still not working.

Can you help me to resolve this ? Any suggestion on how to make this right ?

Here's my `parent layout`

```xml
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <include android:id="@+id/mySearch"
        layout="@layout/layout_search"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/header"/>


    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        layout="@layout/layout_header_back_btn_and_title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mySearch" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

here's my `layout_search.xml`

```xml
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_search"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/size_50_dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/btn_search"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_search"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/size_50_dp"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/icon_search_40"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and `layout_header_back_btn_and_title.xml`

```xml
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    ..>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_arrow_left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitlePage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Keranjang"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/btn_back"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/btn_back"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I expect the back button and title should be below search layout. 
But then it's overlap instead.

[[image: Expected layout]]Expected[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz5aG.png)

[[image: Actual layout]]Actual[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PySSo.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide size of included layouts whenever you use `<include>` in your layouts. Set its height and width as you do in their respective layouts and it should work just fine.

Change your parent layout to this and it should fix your issue.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<include android:id="@+id/mySearch"
    layout="@layout/layout_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/header"/>


<include
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/layout_header_back_btn_and_title"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mySearch" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```